# Where can I store a copy of the source code for my ASP.NET MVC application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, azure, asp.net-mvc-4, azure-storage

I have a MVC4 application that runs on the cloud. I keep multiple backups but I would like also to have a backup some place online.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to where I could put this backup. In total the 3 projects I have occupy about 250MB. Could I store these somehow in an area of the cloud that I am already paying for. What about other places online?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you not use version control? If not, this would be the time to start.

Check out [GitHub](https://github.com) or [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/). Both are free to use for public repositories, and have very affordable plans for private projects.

Comment: Yes I think it might be a good idea to do what you are saying. However if I do use either of these is there a place where I can back up my data that's not local?

Comment: They're cloud hosted version control systems, so all the source code is stored on their servers. In the "cloud", so to speak.

Comment: @fencliff true. I'd like to add that a feature of both Git and Mercurial is that they are distributed, so there's no reason you couldn't have a Git project stored on GitHub, and use this as a remote source for your repo on Bitbucket/your local repo/where-ever for some added redundancy (see distributed workflows - http://git-scm.com/book/en/Distributed-Git-Distributed-Workflows)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend [Microsoft Team Foundation Server](http://tfs.visualstudio.com/en-us/). TFS is integrated into Visual Studio.

Some of the key features

- Up to 5 users **free of charge**
- **Unlimited** number of projects
- **Continuous delivery to Azure** (that can be very handy for you)
- Work item tracking
- Agile planning tools
- Feedback management
- VS Integrated Build (however, that feature is still in preview)

[image: Visual Studio Integrated Build]

I've been using that service for several months and I would definitely recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

I use [dropbox](http://db.tt/qF8lLnC7) for some of my backups, but there are plenty of alternatives, like Amazon S3, or hosting providers like RackSpace etc.

I also have a NAS box that I back up to. I installed SVN on it too, which I access via my laptop and my main desktop PC, so I pretty much always have at least 3 copies of the code at any one time. The SVN repository is also backed up to an external hard disk.

I don't use Azure (yet), so I don't know how their backup services work. I did find this [link](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/services/storage/what-is-a-storage-account/) though, that might help you figure out if you can store your files separately.

I imagine, though, with it being hosted in a cloud based system, your code will be backed up and spread across quite a few servers - so it might not be that much of a problem for you.

Comment: But does dropbox have some limitations as this is 250MB of code in a directory?

Comment: Dropbox is free up to 2GB, and after that you have to pay.